# Blank File is saved when using screencap programatically in Android

Tags: android, screen, screenshot

code snippet

```
void takeSnapShot() 
    {
        Process process = null;
        try
        {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/snapshot/test_2.png" );

        try
        {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
```

I am gettin an empty file saved whereas If i use the same command through adb shell, i get my screen captured.

Any help will be appreciatable

Answer (score 0):

Edit: my previous answer was mistaken, any app can use the screen capture command.

It might be a permission issue. Are you sure you have permission to write to sdcard?
Check this post, which covers your topic:
[How to run android system app without root permisson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615240/how-to-run-android-system-app-without-root-permisson)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following permission to my Manifest.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

**NOTE:** This is a protected permission, my application is a system app and also signed using the platform key.